# Can a runtime shared library call existing symbols?

Tags: c++, symbols, dylib

I have:

- Application **A**
- Dynamic library **D**
- Static library **S**

Where:

- A is linked with static library S at compile time.
- D is compiled without linking S, but uses its header files
- A uses `dlopen` to load D at runtime.

Is it possible for D to use symbols defined in S when being run in A, without D being linked with S at its own compile-time? I.e. can D access symbols in the global namespace?

Other notes:
I need D and A to both be able to call functions from S.
I ideally don't want to alter S.

I've tried this, and I get (when a symbol from S is used in D):

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __Z14myFunctioni
```

I presume this could either be:

1. The existing function 'myFunction(int)' is not available to the shared library (security?)
2. The symbol name for this function has been name mangled in a different way (EDIT: tested with `extern "C"` and ruled this out).

Perhaps I need to compile with different settings, or I have to always link all of S into D? Also would the situation changed if S became a dynamic library itself?

Thankyou

Comment: If the issue is with the name mangling, try disabling name mangling by using `extern "C"` in the function declaration of `myFunction`.

Comment: Thanks Radek, I've ruled this out now using your suggestion. It must be a symbol accessibility issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> External references in the library are resolved using the libraries in that library's dependency list and any other libraries previously opened with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag. **If the executable was linked with the flag "-rdynamic"** (or, synonymously, "--export-dynamic"), then the global symbols in the executable will also be used to resolve references in a dynamically loaded library.

Comment: Ok, this solves it! thankyou! But I now have revealed the next issue: whereby the symbols that weren't previously used in the app are not included at the linking stage. Is there a complimentary flag? --whole-archive seems to be the way forwards, but not working yet.